# Equivalent of Matlab in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I have this code where I want to reference all elements of m in matlab:

```
 NNanm = sum(isnan(m(:)));
```

How would I tell python to reference all the elements of m?

Comment: Use `m[:]` not `m(:)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, you count all nan elements in the matrix. If so, you can do the equivalent thing in python this using numpy with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(m))
```

If you insist on the `sum` function, this also work:

```
np.sum(np.isnan(m))
```